# Libgdx external storage causes NullPointerException on Android

Tags: android, netbeans, storage, external, libgdx

I'm having trouble accessing external storage on Android with the Gdx library. Any help would be appreciated!

Simplified code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class Mp3AndFftTest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Gdx.files.isExternalStorageAvailable();
    }
}
```

This causes:

```
ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cmbryan.android/com.cmbryan.android.Mp3AndFftTest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.cmbryan.android.Mp3AndFftTest.onCreate(Mp3AndFftTest.java:17)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
ERROR   AndroidRuntime      ... 11 more
```

I have correct permissions in the Android manifest, and have tested on the emulator and a real device. What am I missing? Is it because I'm using netbeans, maybe??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 17 is:

```
Gdx.files.isExternalStorageAvailable();
```

right?  `Gdx.files` is null.  This is because you haven't run the GDX initialization code that sets up the global shortcuts in `Gdx`.  You need to create an `ApplicationListener` and pass it to `AndroidApplication.initialize(..)`.

Follow the example here: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup

libGDX's state is ill-defined until you've completed all the expected initialization.  libGDX is more than just a library you can consume pieces out of, its a framework that handles the complete setup and initialization of your app.

Comment: Got it! Sorry to miss the obvious, but I'm doing several 'odd' things which make it more diffifcult to follow the tutorials word-for-word:

1) I'm using netbeans
2) What I really want access to is gdx-audio http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2269&cpage=1, don't care about any graphics, and
3) I only need to develop for Android, so am trying to minimize the linking of desktop and base projects for simplicity! I think I'm on the right track now, but any suggestions as to how to do things better would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not the ideal solution. But you can also use the

```
com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglFiles
```

class directly.
This is the class for creating the Gdx.files object.